# Merge objects on shared Key Value Pair with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays of objects `weather` and `power` that I would like to merge on the shared property `date`. Is there a way to do this with lodash?

```js
 const weather = [
  {
    date: 2,
    weather: 2
  },
  {
    date: 1,
    weather: 1
  },
  {
    date: 3,
    weather: 3
  }
  ];

  const power = [
  {
    date: 1,
    power: 10
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    power: 20
  }];

  const merged = _.merge(weather, power); // <- This does not work as hoped for
```

The expected output contains only the objects that have a matching `date` field (so the `date: 3` object from the `weather` array is dropped).

```js
  const expected = [{
    date: 1,
    weather: 1,
    power: 10
  },
  {
    date: 2,
    weather: 2,
    power: 20
  }];
```

I feel like this should be possible with `union`, `unionBy`, `merge` or similar but I could not find a matching example in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index object by indexing the arrays using [`_.keyBy('date')`](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy), merge the indexes, and extract the values using [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs#values):

```js
const weather = [{"date":2,"weather":2},{"date":1,"weather":1},{"date":3,"weather":3}];

const power = [{"date":1,"power":10},{"date":2,"power":20}];

const weatherIndex = _.keyBy(weather, 'date');
const powerIndex = _.keyBy(power, 'date');

const result = _(powerIndex)
  .pick(_.keys(weatherIndex))
  .merge(_.pick(weatherIndex, _.keys(powerIndex)))
  .values()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: almost, it does still include the object with `date=3` from `weather` that does not have a match in `power` and that should be dropped. I guess one could just iterate over `result`again and check if the values are there. I was mainly asking to see if there is a pretty version to do this though so it would be nice to also integrate this.

Comment: adding a `.filter(function(a){return a.hasOwnProperty('weather') && a.hasOwnProperty('power')})` makes sure that those properties exist. I wonder if there is a nicer solution though?!

Comment: I've used pick to merge only the properties that appear in both of the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

While you have almost a solution with lodash, you could use in plain Javascript a proposal with a hash table and two loops for the arrays.

```js
var weather = [{ date: 2, weather: 2 }, { date: 1, weather: 1 }, { date: 3, weather: 3 }],
    power = [{ date: 1, power: 10 }, { date: 2, power: 20 }],
    hash = new Map,
    merged = power.map(a => {
        var o = {};
        Object.assign(o, a);
        hash.set(a.date, o);
        return o;
    });

weather.forEach(a => hash.has(a.date) && Object.assign(hash.get(a.date), a));
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: +1 for the fact that it works but I find it harder to read then the lodash answer. But that might just be me being more used to lodash then to the new ES features.